# Bind Kendoui dropdownlist to mvvm data-bind value

Tags: kendo-ui

How do i data-bind the MVVM value to my dropdownlist? The input element below works well

`<input class="k-textbox" placeholder="hotel business registration" required  data-bind="value: dataItem.HotelStatusId"/`>

I doesn't when i try to use KendoUI dropdownlist instead

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList().BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.HotelStatuses, "Id", "Name")).Value("#=dataItem.HotelStatusId#").Name("ddl-hotel-status");
```

this does not work either

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList().BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.HotelStatuses, "Id", "Name")).Value("dataItem.HotelStatusId").Name("ddl-hotel-status");
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, here's the working code.

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList().BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.HotelStatuses, "Id", "Name")).Name("ddl-hotel-status").HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object>{{"data-bind", "value: dataItem.HotelStatusId"}})
```